# Django admin didn't allow me to create a group for one app

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to create a group for a specific app like blog, so that group users can only create and edit blog posts. I also assign staff status to the users of that group.

The group is created but it didn't allow me to login in it. After some research, I came to know that if I give access to all of the installed apps it allows me to log in.

any suggestion on how to give permission for any specific app.

Comment: You cannot create groups for specific app, you have to register the models created in that app to the admin site and then create groups with permissions for the models you have created inside the app.

Comment: i am doing the same but i want to create a group that only control all the models inside a single app